# String to JSON in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a sample string I need to convert the string to JSON format. I tried n number of ways but not able to achieve it, It would really sound great if anyone helps me to construct it. sample string position keeps on changing we need to pick data based on the JSON key present.

**Sample String:**

```
sample ="The following are the graphical (non-control) characters defined by
ISO 8859-1 (1987).  DESCRIPTION :  in words aren't all that helpful,
but they're the best we can do in text.  A graphics file illustrating
the character set should be available from the same archive as this
file.RESULT :success INTERPRETATION : ISO 8859-1 (1987).CREATED_BY:Questy.CREATED_ON:29/07/1963"
```

**Required JSON output**

```
{
   "DESCRIPTION":" in words aren't all that helpful but they're the best we can do in text.   A graphics file illustrating the character set should be available from the same archive as thisfile",
   "RESULT":"success",
   "INTERPRETATION":" ISO 8859-1 (1987)",
   "CREATED_BY":"Questy",
   "CREATED_ON":"29/07/1963"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code to solve this problem ?

Comment: You should first try to see a pattern to convert this to dictionary, find out a way to convert uppercase to your keys and rest values. Once this is done, rest should be just dumping to json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to use regex, just string method

```py
sample = ("The following are the graphical (non-control) characters defined "
          "by ISO 8859-1 (1987).  DESCRIPTION :  in words aren't all that "
          "helpful, but they're the best we can do in text.  A graphics file "
          "illustrating the character set should be available from the same "
          "archive as this file.RESULT :success INTERPRETATION : ISO 8859-1 "
          "(1987).CREATED_BY: Questy.CREATED_ON:29/07/1963")

sample = sample.replace('.', '. ').replace('.  ', '. ')

lst = list(map(str.strip, sample.split(':')))

result = {}

for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    if i < len(lst)-2:
        result[lst[i].split()[-1]] = ' '.join(lst[i+1].split()[:-1]).strip('.')
    else:
        result[lst[i].split()[-1]] = lst[i+1].strip('.')
```

```py
>>> result
{'CREATED_BY': 'Questy',
 'CREATED_ON': '29/07/1963',
 'DESCRIPTION': "in words aren't all that helpful, but they're the best we can "
                'do in text. A graphics file illustrating the character set '
                'should be available from the same archive as this file',
 'INTERPRETATION': 'ISO 8859-1 (1987)',
 'RESULT': 'success'}
```